# Add EXDATE with iCalcreator

Tags: icalcreator

Using iCalcreator I'm not understanding how to add an EXDATE field to an existing component and then save that back into the calendar.  Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out.

```php
<?php

require_once 'iCalcreator.php';
use kigkonsult\iCalcreator\{vcalendar,util};

$calendar = new vcalendar();
$calendar->setConfig(['directory' => '...', 'filename' => '...']);
$calendar->parse();

$uid = '...';

$e = $calendar->getComponent($uid);

$s = [['year' => 2017, 'month' => 5, 'day' => 28, 'hour' => 19, 'min' => 0, 'sec' => 0, 'tz' => 'America/Los_Angeles']];
$e->setProperty(util\util::$EXDATE, $s);

$e->setLastModified();
$calendar->setComponent($e, $uid);

$calendar->saveCalendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

as of iCalcreator-2.17.x, you can also set a single exDate

```
$e->setExdate( new DateTime(...));
```